# Reason for such unusual output in c++

Tags: c++, printf

I cannot understand the unusual behavior of this code output.
It prints:

```
 hellooo
monusonuka
```

Code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
printf(" hellooo \n");
char name[7]="sonuka";
char name1[4]={'m','o','n','u'};
printf("%s",name1);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It just so happened that for you, the array containing `{'m', 'o', 'n', 'u'}` was in memory before `sonuka` (which ends with a `\0` and terminates a string). Using the `%s` modifier will make `printf` read until it encounters the null terminator (which `name1` doesn't have as it's not a C-style string.

Comment: 5 answers in 4 seconds... that's goota be a record.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore where is yours? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name1` *must* be NULL-terminated, otherwise `printf` will print as many bytes, as it find, till hitting the `\0`.

It must be

```
char name1[5]={'m','o','n','u', '\0'};
```

What you have is *undefined behaviour* : `printf` prints memory after the memory, allocated for `name1`.

In this case, it seems like your compiler has placed the memory for `name` after `name1`, that's why they are both printed (`name` is correctly `NULL`-terminated, as all literals are).

Answer (score 6):

Your `name1` array is not terminated with a zero character (`'\0'`). The `printf` function prints characters until it finds a zero. In your case it goes past the end of the array. What happens is **undefined behaviour**. A likely outcome is that other variables or garbage is printed to the screen until eventually a `\0` somewhere else in memory is hit, but anything could happen including  your program crashing.

Answer (score 1):

`name1` is not null-terminated, so `printf` just keeps printing chars until a `\0` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf("%s",name1);
```

`s` conversion specifier requires the argument to be a pointer to a C string.

```
char name1[4]={'m','o','n','u'};
```

is not a C string in because the array is not null terminated. Violating the requirement of the conversion speicier invokes undefined behavior and this is why you get this unexpected  result.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print a char array as a string with printf. Try this code:

```
int pointer=0;
while(pointer < 4){
     printf("%c",name1[pointer]);
     pointer++;
}
```